# Saving multiple checkbox into one column

Tags: laravel, checkbox, eloquent

I tried different ways to save multiple checkbox into database. I am so close right now but just the last checkbox value is saving into database. I want them all and I couldn't make it. Here is my html codes.

```
<div class="col-xl-12">                     
<label>1st</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="00101"/>
<label>2nd</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="00102"/>
<label>3rd</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="00103"/>
<label>4th</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="00104"/>
</div>
```

In my controller.

```
  public function store(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request, array(
        'staff' => 'nullable',
        'dmc' => 'nullable',
        'workdone' => 'nullable',
        'product_id' => 'nullable'
    ));

    $ltjob = new Ltjob;
    $ltjob->staff = $request->staff;
    $ltjob->dmc = $request->dmc;
    $ltjob->product_id = $request->product_id;
    foreach ($request->input("data") as $data){
    $ltjob->workdone= $data;
}
    $ltjob->save();
    return redirect()->route('ltjobs.create');
}
```

Still saving last checkbox. When I try the `dd($request->input("data"));`
before the `foreach` it gives me this:

```
  array:3 [▼
  0 => "00101"
  1 => "00102"
  2 => "00104"
]
```

And saving 00104.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bad idea (read about the normalization of databases), but you can do it through getters and setters:

```
public function getDataAttribute()
{
    return !empty($this->attributes['data']) ? explode(',', $this->attributes['data']) : [];
}


public function setDataAttribute($value)
{
   $this->attributes['data'] = implode(',', $value) ? implode(',', $value) : '';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to register more than one field in the same field, you can use

`$table->json('workdone');`

because you are not trying to do it using the loop, you are making an assignment to the workdone field each time the loop is run. Because of this reason, the last value is the value.

Add them to your model file:

`protected $ casts = [
  'workdone' => 'array'
];`

you can solve it by making a definition.

Finally, when registering,

`$ltjob->workdone = $ request->input('data')`

Comment: It will probably work. But i have done all of my works without json in my controller. So i just need to a json one column. json_encode() worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the [migrations in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#columns) you can see the colums.
In my opinion you should use json column.